# How to get currently playing song using SpotifyAPI-NET

Tags: c#, .net, spotify, spotify-app

I want my app to show my currently playing song on Spotify. My access token is stored in `accessToken` variable as string (it has all the necessary scopes). I get my credentials using this line:

```
var spotify = new SpotifyClient(accessToken);
```

Now, I want to get my currently playing track using

```
var track = await spotify.Player.GetCurrentlyPlaying();
```

However, I get an error which says I have to pass a `PlayerCurrentlyPlayingRequest` request to the `GetCurrentlyPlaying` function. I don't know what should I pass there.

Comment: Check [this](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/docs/next/introduction/)

Comment: @kumi95 I read this, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The class `PlayerCurrentlyPlayingRequest` allows you to specify the `AdditionalTypes` of **Track**, **Episode** or **All** which is the only required Property to be set, you can additionally provide the `Market` but this is what you need to provide to that method.

> Full Disclosure I maintain my own independent Spotify SDK to this one

Comment: In fact, according to [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#object-currentlyplayingobject), the only required query parameter is market. Even after I learnt that, I ran into further issues with obtaining the track's name. It appears that even after you get the track with `var track = await spotify.Player.GetCurrentlyPlaying(new PlayerCurrentlyPlayingRequest { Market = "from_token" });`, you can't get the song's name. That's why I changed my version to the latest stable and now everything works just fine. Thanks for help.