# How can I get the currently playing track from spotify using SpotifyAPI.Web, C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use SpotifyAPI.Web for C#, in order to get the currently playing track from my Spotify-player.

Here is my code

```
var spotify = new SpotifyClient("acces token");


var currentTrack = await spotify.Player.GetCurrentlyPlaying(new PlayerCurrentlyPlayingRequest { Market = "from_token" });
```

and I found this post, it's very similar to mine but it doesn't help me.
[How to get currently playing song using SpotifyAPI-NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553848/how-to-get-currently-playing-song-using-spotifyapi-net)

At this point I get a SpotifyAPI.Web.APIException: "Invalid username"

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: See [invalid username for PlayerCurrentlyPlaying()](https://github.com/zmb3/spotify/issues/69)

Comment: So I found a this link: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/
but what do I have to change in my code to get another authorization?

Comment: Not c# version but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771467/spotify-api-player-currently-playing-endpoint-not-returning-device-in-response/75773053#75773053) is node.js version, replace device url into current play API.